# Gpgkeys can't be retrieved

Tags: ppa, repository

I added a repository using `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/next`

After adding it i get the message:

```
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpk2n9xi/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpk2n9xi/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 0624A220 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpgkeys: key FE85409EEAB40ECCB65740816AF0E1940624A220 can't be retrieved
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

I even installed `y-ppa-manger` and tried importing all the keys. Got success message there but that doesn't solve the GPG key issue.

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions!

Comment: How "new" is the PPA you added?  When was the PPA created?  Does it actually contain any packages?

Comment: Its the standard ppa for installing ubuntu tweak tool. So i guess it would be containing the required packages.

Comment: Its sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/next instead of sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa. Sorry. But error is same. Writing mistake.

Comment: I just confirmed the key is on the keyserver, do me a favor and do this command and see if it downloads correctly (you do not need sudo for this command): `gpg --recv-key --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 0x0624A220`   If it doesn't download right, then either your system isn't able to communicate with the keyservers right, or something else is up with your system.  If all goes well, though, it'll return output [similar to this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6600183/)

Comment: The key is not imported through this also. Getting the same message of key can't be imported. I am able to update using sudo so i think network should not be the problem.What could be the possible communication error with keyservers?

Comment: it could very well be your network, the problem is that key DOES exist, so either your system is just failing to communicate with the server, or your DNS is poisoned, what do you see in the "ANSWER" section when you do `dig keyserver.ubuntu.com`?

Comment: In our case in was VPN issue - it was blocking connection to port `11371`

Answer (score 7):

Try importing the key with :

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-key --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com FE85409EEAB40ECCB65740816AF0E1940624A220
```

If it doesn't work try with :

```
sudo aptitude -o Acquire::http::No-Cache=True -o Acquire::BrokenProxy=true update
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Same message

Comment: The first one worked for me. I had this problem while trying to install docker